# How to have proper JsonNode field in my Ebean Entity?

Tags: java, json, playframework, jackson, ebean

I am working under play framework 2.2.1 and I need a quick blob saving entity in my data model (a quick user settings documents that needs to be saved for the client side). I have done that many time but this time I would like Ebean to take care of the grunt work for me.

I would like to make Ebean recognize jackson's `JsonNode` and `ObjectNode` as column types. Here is what my class looks like:

```
@Entity
public class UserSettings extends Model {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private JsonNode blob;

    // [... getters setters and whatnot ...]
}
```

I would like Ebean to directly create a TEXT column in my table (using PostgreSQL) and parse and stringify the column when needed automatically. I have not found code examples or documentation relating to this kind of features. This looks so basic it should be possible. Or am I really wrong?
Ebean already supports joda time, it would seem weird it cannot support adding custom object types or json blobs, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at:
com.avaje.ebean.config.ScalarTypeConverter

or alternatively
com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.type.ScalarTypeBaseVarchar

and perhaps as some examples to work off...

com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.type.ScalarTypeUUID
com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.type.ScalarTypeClob

The first question is whether you are storing the JSON as Clob or Varchar (or perhaps you need 2 different options).

> **Update:** As of Ebean ORM version 4.6.3 there is now built in support for storing both `JsonNode` and `Map<String,Object>` into
>   various database types (Clob,Varchar,Blob plus Postgres JSON and JSONB
>   data types).
>
> Refer to:
>
> - https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/issues/297
> - https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/issues/299

Comment: Fortunately there has been a major improvement to handling JSON with Ebean ORM, thanks to @Rob: https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/issues/299 / https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ebean/tcqAvmHf_FI

Comment: Also note there is an enhancement request to support Jackson beans via ObjectMapper (in addition to the JsonNode and Map<String,Object> types). This is logged as https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/issues/542